# Need to show All option is Letter-based Navigation using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

I'm going to apply a letter-based navigation to filter the content of a table and a list. When clicking one of the letters, filters the list/table to show only the items in the list/table that start with that letter.

But the problem i'm facing is "All List". I need to display "all" link as well, Can any one please help me to add "All" link..

```
$(function () {
    var _alphabets = $('.alphabet > a');
    var _contentRows = $('#countries-table tbody tr');

    _alphabets.click(function () {      
        var _letter = $(this), _text = $(this).text(), _count = 0;

        _alphabets.removeClass("active");
        _letter.addClass("active");

        _contentRows.hide();
        _contentRows.each(function (i) {
            var _cellText = $(this).children('td').eq(0).text();
            if (RegExp('^' + _text).test(_cellText)) {
                _count += 1;
                $(this).fadeIn(400);
            }
        });                   
    });
});
```

Here is the [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CARcQ/) link...

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[updated]**

an easy one

Just add this line :

```
if(_text == 'All') _text = '.';
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/CARcQ/4/)**

**Edit :**

according to your wish, this code allows you to fade the letters that don't have words:

```
_alphabets.not(':first').css('opacity','0.5');
_contentRows.each(function(){
    var beg = $(this).children('td:first').text().trim()[0];
    $('.alphabet a:eq('+(beg.charCodeAt(0)-64)+')').css('opacity','1.0');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/CARcQ/8/)**

Explanation: what I did here is getting the first letter of each first td in all trs then convert it to ascii (A=65 ..) then deduct 64 so that the first index starts from 1 (A) and so on (since index 0 is for "All")

Note: you don't have to use regex at all since you are just comparing the first characters, you can increase the efficiency by eleminating the regex .

Comment: Wow,done... Thanks for help... :).. One question? , Can we fade the Letter bg color, if there is no data...?

Comment: e.g. there is no data for "D" category, and i need to add a class for letter "d". Can it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Apply the **Regex** only when the text is not equal to `All`

```
$(function () {
    var _alphabets = $('.alphabet > a');
    var _contentRows = $('#countries-table tbody tr');

    _alphabets.click(function () {
        var _letter = $(this),
            _text = $(this).text(),
            _count = 0;

        _alphabets.removeClass("active");
        _letter.addClass("active");

        _contentRows.hide();
        _contentRows.each(function (i) {
            var _cellText = $(this).children('td').eq(0).text();
            if (_text === 'All') {
                _count += 1;
                $(this).fadeIn(400);
            } else {
                if (RegExp('^' + _text).test(_cellText)) {
                    _count += 1;
                    $(this).fadeIn(400);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CARcQ/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

Just show all `tr` on`click()`

```
$('a').first().click(function(){
$('#countries-table tbody tr').fadeIn(400);
});
```

[link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CARcQ/5/)